# How to run a python script that executes every 5 minutes BUT in the meantime executes some other script

Tags: python, time

I don't want the code to go the sleep in these 5 minutes and just waits. I want to run some other code block or script in the meantime.
How to run a python script that executes every 5 minutes BUT in the meantime executes some other script it code block until the 5 minute time is reached again. 
e.g I want to run 3 functions . One to run every 5 minutes. another every 1 minutes. another every 10-20 seconds.

Comment: try asyncio, https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to control your subprocess and eventually kill it after 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

delay = 1 # time between your next script execution
wait = delay
t1 = time.time()

while True:
   t2 = time.time() - t1

   if t2 >= wait:
      wait += delay
        # execute your script once every 5 minutes (now it is set to 1 second)
   # execute your other code here
```

First, you need to get the time of your script, then you need a variable to store "wait time" of your script (in this case "wait").

Every time your script time is higher or equal to "wait" delay variable is added to wait and code is executed.

And for multiple delays it's:

```
import time

delay = [1, 3]
wait = [delay[0], delay[1]]
t1 = time.time()

while True:
   t2 = time.time() - t1

   for i in range(len(wait)):
       if t2 >= wait[i]:
           wait[i] += delay[i]
           if i==0:
               print("This is executed every second")
           if i==1:
               print("This is executed every 3 second")
```

Comment: I think it would be better to release assigned resources and have a cronjob or other OS scheduling handling the task

Comment: What about more than two scripts with different timing for execution? 
I have three separate scripts. one every 5 min. one every 1 min. another every 10 seconds.

Comment: You would need a list "delay" for different delays, list "wait". Then you would use 
for i in range(len(wait)) or something to check if script time is higher or equal to every "wait" value. I would also suggest you use a module, but this is way without additional modules.